# Excluding duplicates with Python List Comprehension when referencing multiple values of an array

Tags: python, list, numpy, list-comprehension

The task is to return every row of a 2D data set that has an entry whose value is greater than the column it is a part of.

I'm trying to see if there's a more clever way to do this with list comprehension:

```py
data = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [86, 4, 14]])
sliced = [data[i] for i in range(len(data))
            for j in range(len(data[i]))
                if data[i,j] > np.mean(data[:,j])]
```

This code returns:

```
[array([7, 8, 9]), array([10, 11, 12]), array([10, 11, 12]), array([13, 14, 15]), array([13, 14, 15]), array([86,  4, 14]), array([86,  4, 14])]
```

You can see it accomplishes the task, but it leaves duplicates in rows like [10, 11, 12] where both values 11 and 12 are greater than the mean of their columns.

Is there a clever way to exclude additional datapoints from the same row during list comprehension? I could remove duplicates afterward, but in a hypothetical context that might remove valid data that happens to be identical.

Comment: With `data[i]` you are selecting a whole row, not elements of a row.

Comment: Yep, my intention was to return the whole row of any row that fits the conditions

Comment: List comprehensions are nice but there’s probably a way of doing it in NumPy, no?

Comment: @AMC, I think we need to first get the intention right.

Comment: @hpaulj Agreed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [45]: data = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14
    ...: , 15], [86, 4, 14]])                                                   
In [46]: data                                                                   
Out[46]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15],
       [86,  4, 14]])

In [49]: [data[i] for i in range(len(data)) 
    ...:             for j in range(len(data[i])) 
    ...:                 if data[i,j] > np.mean(data[:,j])]                     
Out[49]: 
[array([7, 8, 9]),
 array([10, 11, 12]),
 array([10, 11, 12]),
 array([13, 14, 15]),
 array([13, 14, 15]),
 array([86,  4, 14]),
 array([86,  4, 14])]
```

I intended to get the list comprehension right, but then realized that it was easier to approach this from a numpy perspective:

```
In [55]: m = data.mean(axis=0)                                                  
In [56]: m                                                                      
Out[56]: array([20.16666667,  7.33333333,  9.83333333])
In [57]: data>m                                                                 
Out[57]: 
array([[False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True]])
In [58]: np.any(data>m, axis=1)                                                 
Out[58]: array([False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True])
In [59]: data[_,:]                                                              
Out[59]: 
array([[ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15],
       [86,  4, 14]])
```

A list comprehension version:

```
In [64]: [row for row in data if any(row > m)]                                  
Out[64]: 
[array([7, 8, 9]),
 array([10, 11, 12]),
 array([13, 14, 15]),
 array([86,  4, 14])]
```

though that still makes use of the numpy `row>m` test.  The difficulty with a pure list approach is that your desire mean is taken down the columns.

```
[row for row in data ... if ... mean(row)]
```

doesn't work because that's the wrong dimension; we want `mean(col)` or as you do `data[:,j]`.